# How to execute anonymous function using eval or Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to execute jquery using eval function

```
function hello(){
    console.log("hello");
}

$(function() {
    hello();
   
})();
```

I have above code as String value and passing to java script eval function.
It's giving `TypeError: $(...) is not a function`. How to load Jquery dynamically and execute above code to print "hello" using eval/Function or  $.globalEval.

Comment: "*How to load Jquery dynamically*" is a very different question than the one you asked in the title of your post

Answer (score 1):

It works fine, you need to remove the last `()` from `$(function() {})`.

does this help ?

```js
eval(`
  function hello(){
    console.log("hello");
  }

  $(function() {
    hello();
   
  });

`)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```